# gzunip -c and gzcat

Tags: performance, unix, gzip

Could anyone tell why is `gunzip -c` so much slower than `gzcat` ?

I though they were essentially the same..

cheers,

f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They provide the same functionality, and it would not surprise me if they were the same executable (certainly `zcat` and `gunzip` are on my linux box).

I wonder how you have measured the performance? Are you seeing performance differences due to disk caching, or some other external influence?

Comment: That's it.. I had the same idea. but in practice worked different. It's an AIX box here, and gzcat did not come by default so what I did was to add an alias to 'gunzip -c' as gzcat. Happened that I have an app running in this box that calls gzcat all the time for some massive files and using this alias basically screwed the performance, installing gzcat brought it back to normal... That's why I asked..